# The method getConfig() is undefined for the type Signs

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

When I try to get the config to test if it equals null, I get an error saying

> The method getConfig() is undefined for the type Signs

I have no errors in my other class, and I don't know what the problem is. Here is my current code:

```java
public class Signs implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent e) {
        if (e.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("[shop]")) {
            Block attached = e.getBlock().getRelative(0, -1, 0);
            String name = e.getPlayer().getDisplayName();
            if (!(attached.getType() == Material.CHEST))
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please place the shop on a chest!");
            else {
                if (!e.getPlayer().hasPermission("shops.create"))
                    e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You don't have permission to create a shop! (shops.create)");
                else {
                    if (!Arrays.asList("open", "closed").contains(e.getLine(1).toLowerCase())) {
                        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must specify if the shop is open or closed on the second line!");
                    } else {
                        boolean closed = true;
                        if ("open".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getLine(1))) {
                            closed = false;
                        }

                        String lineThree = closed ? "§cClosed" : "§aOpen";
                        e.setLine(3, lineThree);
                        e.setLine(0, "§9[Shop]");
                        e.setLine(1, "§b" + name + "'s");
                        e.setLine(2, "§bShop");
                        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Shop Created!");
                        e.getPlayer().playSound(e.getPlayer().getLocation(), Sound.LEVEL_UP, 10, 10);
                        if(getConfig().getStringList(name) == null);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            Block b = e.getClickedBlock();
            Block a = b.getRelative(0, -1, 0);
            int ax = a.getX();
            int ay = a.getY();
            int az = a.getZ();
            Material m = b.getType();
            if (!(m == Material.SIGN_POST)) {
                return;
            } else {
                Sign sign = (Sign) e.getClickedBlock().getState();
                if ((sign.getLine(0).equalsIgnoreCase("§9[Shop]"))) {
                    if ((sign.getLine(3).equalsIgnoreCase("§aOpen"))) {
                        p.sendMessage("I opened the shop!");
                        World world = e.getPlayer().getWorld();
                        Location chestLocation = new Location(world, ax, ay, az);
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because you are calling getConfig()  method without implementing it. I don't see it in your code. if(getConfig().getStringList(name) == null);

Comment: then were do i implement it?

Comment: In the first place this statement does not add any value to your code. If you need getConfig() method implement then you should implement in the class scope, as a method of Signs.

Comment: hehe im new to this and you completely lost me on that ^

Comment: What are you expecting by checking null in the line if(getConfig().getStringList(name) == null); ? If you want to do something after checking null then you should if(getConfig().getStringList(name) == null) { doSomething }.

Comment: if it is null then there would be a new section in the config created for them

Comment: What does this getConfig() method should do?

Comment: it should get the config and check if there name is in the config if it is then it will send them the list that is under their name!

Comment: i just noticed i would have to do .getStringList() twice for the first list of names and then the list of shops in a name!

Answer (score 3):

`getConfig()` is a method implemented by `JavaPlugin`. In order to use it, you have to have an instance of whichever class `extends JavaPlugin` (this class is normally called `Main`).

In your `Main` class, you could add a static variable which contains the configuration file, and is initialized `onEnable()`

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    public static FileConfiguration config;

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        config = getConfig();

        //other code in your onEnable()
    }
}
```

Then, you can use the variable `Main.config` anywhere outside of your `Main` class that you would like to use your plugin's configuration file

```
public class Signs implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onSignChange(SignChangeEvent e){
        //your code
        if(Main.config.getStringList(name) == null){
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to set the `config` variable to `null` in your `onDisable()` to prevent memory leaks that could occur if the server is reloaded

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

    public static FileConfiguration config;

    @Override
    public void onDisable(){
        config = null;

        //other code in your onDisable()
    }
}
```